# Taxonomy fields on Profile2 edit form

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, users

I'm hoping someone can help me. I've been stuck on this problem for a while and can't find help. I'm relatively new to theming in drupal, so forgive me if this is a basic question.

I have a taxonomy term reference field on a profile2. The taxonomy term reference has multiple fields (name, poc, number). I would like all the taxonomy fields display on the Profile2 user edit page. This would allow a checklist type effect for each individual's profile. Right now only the taxonomy term name displays on the edit profile2 form.

Is there a hook that I can use to make the Profile2 edit form display all the taxonomy fields?

I was looking at `profile2_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)` but I couldn't get it to work/not sure how to call the taxonomy field in my **template.php** file.